# Please help me identify this car part

Tags: part-identification, renault

I've had a bunch of trouble with my new car(Dacia Dokker, bought in Janury), mostly because the garage people are idiots/assholes.

After the latest problem I found the following part lying loose under the back chairs and we also found a plastic nut(the type that also holds the jack in place in the back) in the back wich we can't find the source for.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Codes on the inside are

85042
5283 R
Mp6818

But these don't give me anything relevant on google.
I want to know what this is so the garage can't make up anymore bullshit.

Comment: Hmm well it looks plastic to me so I would think it isnt anything too mechanically important. Curious to see if anyone knows!

Comment: What work was done?

Comment: My blinkers weren't working and they said the problem had to do with the cabling at the tow hook. That's all I know.

Comment: Could it be a cover / protector for the end of a seat rail or edge of a fokding seat or rear seat catch?

Comment: Oh and they also replaced the AC because it wasn't working(forgot because that problem was noticed 2 months ago already) I'm currently checking anything I can too see if anything's missing in the engine or anywhere else ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bumper mounting bracket. Not sure if it's front or rear.

---

Google image search for `850425283R`

[image: Google image search for 850425283R]

---

Some Russian auto parts site has `BRKTMTG RR BMPR` (Bracket Mount Rear Bumper?) in a description for it.

- https://www.avtodubai.ru/partnum/850425283R.html

[image: 850425283R]

---

And finally here is Ukrainian classified ad, which lists it as right front bumper fastening bracket ([Кронштейн крепления бампера правый передний](https://translate.google.com/#ru/en/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)) for Renault (Dacia) Duster.

- https://besplatka.ua/obyavlenie/prodam-kronshtein-fiksiruyushchii-reno-daster-850425283r-e158b9

[image: Ukrainian classified ad]

Comment: ugh, from the way the codes were printed I thought 85042 and 5283 R were 2 different codes, now I feel like a dumbass. Too bad all the sites are in slavic languages but at least now I know it's part of the bumper and know where to look.

Comment: And googling the code in the format of your picture of the original renault bag I found a page where they specify its location: http://apc.onwheels.ru/renault.lmz?t=2679&c=246&eq=61552&gr=N551010&tid=1467 (part nr 19) , Now I'm gonna check in the morning if they just forgot about it or maybe put in another one and this was a spart part of sorts they left behind.